# Mobile first - Encrypted Cache Success and Failure Handler

Tags: javascript, local-storage, method-chaining, jsonstore, ibm-mobilefirst

In MobileFirst V6.3 once we call a JSON Store API, Success and failure can be captured using **.then()** & **.fail()**. To chain the API calls we can use multiple **.then()**. Let's say,

```
WL.JSONStore.startTransaction()
.then(function () {
  var data = [{name: 'carlos'}];
  return WL.JSONStore.get(collectionName).add(data);
})
.then(function () {
  var docs = [{_id: 1, json: {name: 'carlos'}}];
  return WL.JSONStore.get(collectionName).remove(docs);
})
.then(function () {
  return WL.JSONStore.commitTransaction();
})

.fail(function (errorObject) {
  WL.JSONStore.rollbackTransaction()
  .then(function () {
    // Handle rollback success.
  })

  .fail(function () {
    // Handle rollback failure.
  })
});
```

Since Encrypted Cache API has its own API's callback methods, like below.

```
WL.EncryptedCache.open(credentials, create_if_none, onCompleteHandler, onErrorHandler);
```

How to handle Encrypted Cache API chain call's similar to JSON Store[Avoiding callback methods for each API Call's]?

If its not available in out-of-box, is any work around available to achieve the same.

A snippet will be helpful.

Comment: Note that Encrypted Cache is a deprecated feature. You should use JSONStore instead.

Comment: @IdanAdar, I couldn't find anywhere that Encrypted Cache is deprecated. Even in IBM Knowledge center for MobileFirst. https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/what_s_new/c_deprecations.html

Comment: You're right, that's strange. Disregard my previous comment for the time being.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The recommendation is to use JSONStore.
- Chaining callbacks is not supported out of the box.

The way to do it, is for someone to implement wrappers for the methods that are using callbacks. If you insist on doing that, you'll need to implement something that will look like this:

```
function wrapper() {
   var myVar = $.Deferred();
   Wl.EncryptedCache.open(credentials, create_if_none, myVar.resolve, myVar.reject);
   return myVar;
}
```

From the user's code:

```
wrapper.then(
 function() {success flow...},
 function() {failure flow...}
);
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort. Let me give a try with your suggestion and update. Also, I would like to know is there a way to interrupt the chain method flow if we go with your suggestion.

Comment: Because it is not supported, I don't know. It's not tested. You'll have to experiment.